# How does Swift's Scanner .charactersToBeSkipped work?

Tags: swift

Can somebody explain, why the scanner stops at the first whitespace in "Scan 1" (see code) though default .charactersToBeSkipped is set to .whitespacesAndNewlines? Looks like I don't
get the concept of skipped characters.

Scan 2 - 4 are just test cases. Xcode 11 / Swift 4

Playground:

```
let hexCs = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890abcdefABCDEF")
let hexWhiteCs = CharacterSet().union(hexCs).union(.whitespacesAndNewlines)

let ascii = "<19 19 19 19>"

let scanner = Scanner(string:ascii)
_ = scanner.scanString("<")
let reset = scanner.currentIndex
/// Scan 1:
var result = scanner.scanCharacters(from: hexCs) // "19"
/// Scan 2:
scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = nil
scanner.currentIndex = reset
result = scanner.scanCharacters(from: hexCs) // "19"
/// Scan 3:
scanner.currentIndex = reset
result = scanner.scanCharacters(from: hexWhiteCs) // "19 19 19 19"
/// Scan 4:
scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = .whitespacesAndNewlines
scanner.currentIndex = reset
result = scanner.scanCharacters(from: hexWhiteCs) // "19 19 19 19"

let expected = result!.filter { !CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.contains($0.unicodeScalars.first!) } // "19191919"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsscanner/1410204-characterstobeskipped?language=objc) can:

> Characters to be skipped are skipped prior to the scanner examining the target. For example, if a scanner ignores spaces and you send it a `scanInt:` message, it skips spaces until it finds a decimal digit or other character. **While an element is being scanned, no characters are skipped**.

Comment: I have probably overlooked that a hundred times, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: that's probably how it's meant: `var hexStr = ""
while let hex = scanner.scanCharacters(from: hexCs) { hexStr.append(hex) }`